# How to update hplip to 3.13.8?

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp, hplip

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The synaptic package manager says that the latest hplip version is 3.12. But there are more updated versions. I bought a printer HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 1515 All-in-one and found that the minimum hplip version for this printer should be 3.13.8. (http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/combined.html).

1. Why does the synaptic package manager shows that the latest version is 3.12?
2. How can I update that hplip version from 3.12 to 3.13.8?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why does the synaptic package manager shows that the latest version is 3.12 ?

Because for 12.04 `3.12.2-1ubuntu3.4` is the latest stable version on release. And nobody backported the package (there is no need for it due to the reason below).

2. How can I update that hplip version from 3.12 to 3.13.8 ?

   - [You can do it yourself](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html). HP has an excellent track record and provides installers. And their installers are excellent so nobody feels the need to backport hplip.
   - Update your system to 14.04 (uses version 3.14.3) or 14.10 (3.14.6).

Comment: What is backportation ?

Comment: "backport" is making software available for versions older than what it was intended for.